# Powershell Add Local Group to Local Group

Tags: powershell

I'm able to properly add a local user to a local group on my machine, but I can't add a local group to another local group.  What is the syntax for this?

```
$targetGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computerName/$targetGroupName,group"    
$targetGroup.Add("WinNT://$computerName/$groupName")
```

The above results in this error:

```
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "A new member could not be added to a local group because the member has the wrong account type.
```

I'm trying to add a local group to a local group, in Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Your title says you are adding a group to a group. Your question asks about a user to a group. Your code looks like group to a group. Which is it just to clarify? Also what is the OS? Apparently this behavior is discouraged. [Source] (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681621(v=ws.10).aspx) explains (on bottom) this might not work as you expect. _The user token only reflects the direct local group that the user is added to as a member._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest domain groups, but local group nesting is not supported. This technet article explains in detail.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681621(v=ws.10).aspx

Have you considered listing all the users of the "subgroup" and adding them to the target group? This obviously would not create a permanent linking like a sub group would. But it would ensure each member of the "subgroup" are members of the target group at the time the script is run.

Comment: That's the same article I referenced :)

Answer (score 1):

Local groups cannot be added to other local groups. This is a limitation of Windows. It's not that you don't have to right code; it just can't be done.

### Reference

[A local group cannot be found if it is nested inside another group on a Windows Server-based or Windows-based client](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/974815)